# Creating a full with banner with 3 images using bootsrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to be able to divide the images up, on one row, into 3 separate but equally sized columns that take up the space of the whole page. Right now, I'm getting 3 unevenly sized rows. 
So far this is what I have...

```
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span4">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bandanaworld.com/20108.JPG" alt="img">
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.wholesaleforeveryone.com/content/images/blank/600/solid_color.gif" alt="img">
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://sdihousing.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Solid-Colors-Spectrum-Blue.png" alt="img">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If it makes a difference, the images I will be using in the project have the same size, but I would also like to learn how to do it with different sized images, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after your div with the class `row` add for each column a div with class `col-md-4`
which means the row will contains 3 columns :   **[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4908/)**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">

            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bandanaworld.com/20108.JPG" alt="img">

        </div>
             <div class="col-md-4">

            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.wholesaleforeveryone.com/content/images/blank/600/solid_color.gif" alt="img">

             </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">

            <img class="img-responsive" src="http://sdihousing.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Solid-Colors-Spectrum-Blue.png" alt="img">

            </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

the images will dynamically change the size depend on the window size , so you don't have to care about them

Comment: Thank you, this works great! Do you happen to have any idea how I can make each of these images fit the size of the screen in respect to their col div?

Answer (score 0):

Change `class="span4"` to `class="col-md-4"`