# Fitting images to their div on a screen using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I recently [asked a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28752728/creating-a-full-with-banner-with-3-images-using-bootsrap) that a is kind of related to this but I still need some help.  Now that I have that part done, I would like to know how I can make this images fit the size of the browser within their respective divs. Therefore the page would just be the 3 images side by side, no scroll up or down. I thought that having a "container fluid class would help me in this respect but it hasn't. I don't care about the quality of the images in terms because I will be using very hi-def photos, but if there is anything that I should keep in mind in this respect please feel free to notify me. Here is the code so far:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">

        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bandanaworld.com/20108.JPG" alt="img">

    </div>
         <div class="col-md-4">

        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.wholesaleforeveryone.com/content/images/blank/600/solid_color.gif" alt="img">

         </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">

        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://sdihousing.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Solid-Colors-Spectrum-Blue.png" alt="img">

        </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add some classes to your **html** :

```
<div class="imageContainer container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="ImageColumn col-md-4">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.bandanaworld.com/20108.JPG" alt="img">
    </div>
    <div class="ImageColumn col-md-4">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.wholesaleforeveryone.com/content/images/blank/600/solid_color.gif" alt="img">
    </div>
    <div class="ImageColumn col-md-4">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://sdihousing.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Solid-Colors-Spectrum-Blue.png" alt="img">
    </div>
</div>
```

And some **css**:

```
 .imageContainer {
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
}
.imageContainer .row, .imageContainer .ImageColumn {
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
}
.imageContainer .ImageColumn img {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

here is the [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/5077/)

### But I must warn you the result with real photos can look bad because of image stretch: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/5078/)

## UPD:

as suggested in comments - you can change class to col-xs-4 so it would behave the same on all devices.

## UPD 2:

I added something similar like Ihover square effect 4 but without rotation.
It required quite a change in css transitions.
Here is the example:

## [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/5101/)

Comment: Awesome! I'm only having one more problem, I can't seem to get it running with this [css](http://gudh.github.io/ihover/dist/) to wrap the images in instead of the actual images.

Comment: Setting image height to 100% while using img-responsive (adds 100% width) is not correct. The images will always be distorted. The code posted by @cmcas is correct. If you want to have the 3 images ALWAYS in one row, simply change the column class from col-md-4 to col-xs-4.

Comment: @JoeConlin - I warned cmcas about the image stretching in my answer. Also I think he asked about full-height too with no padding between images.
cmcas - you want to have the hover effect as on the link  provided on the images?

Comment: Yes, I have placed the images into the respective "ihover" class, but no cigar. @JoeConlin - Maksym is correct.

Comment: I don't understand why anyone would ever allow images to get distorted but if there is no concern for that then yes, using the method suggested by @MaksymStepanenko will work. Having said that, also applying the .col-xs-4 is going to make the images almost unrecognizable on mobile.

Comment: I would agree with @JoeConlin on that. Distorted images do not look good. Can you explain a bit more what are you trying to achive?

Comment: My end goal is to have the product that you've produced from the fiddle but have those images within the Square Effect 4 of ihover.